# Radius of Convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n!(2x+1)^n$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I'm trying to find out what the radius of convergence is for the power series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n!(2x+1)^n$$

I figured I'd use the Ratio Test, but then I would just end up with $(2x+1)\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)$, so I thought the radius would be $$-1 \leq 2x+1 \leq 1$$
which would be $$-1 \leq x \leq 0$$

But I guess I got the idea wrong, would appreciate some help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: $n!$ will always make it divergent unless it it multiplied by ZERO. What does that mean for $x$?

Comment: Why did you just ignore the $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$u_n(x)=n!(2x+1)^n$$

If $ x=-\frac 12 $, the series converges.

If $ x\ne -\frac 12 $, then

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\Bigl|\frac{u_{n+1}(x)}{u_n(x)}\Bigr|=$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(n+1)|2x+1|=+\infty$$

$$\implies \sum u_n(x) \text{ diverges} $$

So the Radius of convergence is $ R=0$.

Comment: Why would x = $-\frac{1}{2}$ work here though? $0 * \infty$ is not zero?

Comment: @JakeDrone I said, if $ x\ne -1/2$

Comment: Yes, but if x does equal to $\frac{-1}{2}$ then it is 0 times infinity isn't it?

Comment: @JakeDrone No, if $ x=-1/2$, you don't  need the ration test, because in this case the general term is zero, so the series converges.

Comment: @JakeDrone By definition, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n!(2x+1)^n$$ is $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N}n!(2x+1)^n$$ So, for $x=-1/2$ you get $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N}n!(0)^n = \lim_{N\to\infty} 0 = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test actually gives the expression
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[(2x+1)(n+1)\Big]
$$
And you want this limit to be finite (actually you want it to be between $-1$ and $1$, but that detail turns out to be irrelevant in this case). When can that happen? Exactly when $2x+1$ is zero. Never otherwise. So the series converges at $x=-\frac12$ and the radius of convergence is $0$.